# How to add NPM INSTALL to my Visual Studio pre-build events?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm

I have this code in my pre-build window:

> echo "cd $(SolutionDir)Angular2MVC\SPA" &&^
>
> cd "$(SolutionDir)Angular2MVC\SPA" &&^
>
> npm install &&^
>
> echo "building Angular2MVC" &&^
>
> ng build &&^
>
> echo 'copy files' &&^
>
> xcopy /I /E /Y "$(SolutionDir)Angular2MVC\SPA\dist"
> "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\NgApp"

It works greate without **ng build** part.
With ng build I've got this error:

> ...
>
> added 1085 packages in 76.594s
>
> node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`

but the folder is NOT empty! What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Nop. Just abandoned this case.